# How can I see my project using npm start?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I run npm start, I am prompted with with message mentioning that there is an UPDATE : The latest version of `serveis` 14.1.2 and I runed npm update -g serve, but it's doesn't change.
And when I put http://localhost:3000 I got error saying "404 the requested path could not be found"

[image] [image]

Comment: Did you try `192.168.1.134....` ?

Comment: I see that you used ^C to kill the process. Did you do this before or after you got the 404? The web server needs to be running (but I'm sure you already know this)

Comment: Could you put the output log? It’s difficult to understand the problem if I don’t know where to begin.

Comment: What is output log? npm start?

Comment: `npm start` is most likely using `serve` from `node_modules` not global. Looks like you are hitting your app ok at localhost and it is returning a 404 otherwise you would get a connection/site unreachable error.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you closed "npm start" at the end of your print.

If you are in your project folder and give the command
`npm start` it loads, but when you give the command `"ctrl+c"`, the server is closed and you can no longer see the project.

Try `npm run build` this is the command to generate production build directory. Every time you modify any React document, this command is necessary

https://www.letsreact.org/how-to-run-and-build-a-react-app/

Comment: Yes, I know it. But even though when I didn't "ctrl + c" I can't see my project. I got error like "404 the requested path could not be found"

Comment: Try `npm run build` this is the command to generate production build directory. Every time you modify any React document